# Is it possible to append or prepend FormData Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a multiple file select.
I will use FormData as my `data` in ajax.

I have a lot input form in my form, but this one for handling upload file:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12 ">
  <label for="file">Upload Foto</label>
  <input name="file[]" id="file" type="file" multiple >    
</div>
```

Now, with jquery :

```
$('#upload').submit(function () {
  var form = $('#upload');
  var inputFile = $('input#file');
  var filesToUpload = inputFile[0].files;

  // make sure there is file(s) to upload
    if (filesToUpload.length > 0) {
      // provide the form data that would be sent to sever through ajax
      var formData = new FormData();
      for (var i = 0; i < filesToUpload.length; i++) {
         var file = filesToUpload[i];
         formData.append("file[]", file, file.name);
         console.log(file) ; //debug
      }
    }
```

When I select two file, I got those two files. And continously, I select (click) again and I choose one file. You know, I just got one file. My expectation is : there are three files. Is it possible ???
For any help, it so appreciated

Comment: when you click on file upload,old selected files will get removed.If you want to save all three then you should use jquery ajax file up loader that starts uploading files immediately

Comment: But my case is : dont upload immediately. It will be submit with another input later on submit button.

Comment: on file uploader change event hide file uploader and create dynamically new input file tag.On form submit you can take files from multiple file uploaders

Comment: Thanks, what I should store on those input ? I need all information like FormData save to I use on ajax

Comment: U have clue about that @FadlyDzil?